# Issue with async promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

i'm trying to get a list of matching entities from a querystring. i'm using s3 to store my objects.

The problem is that the promise that resolves the 'main promise' is ansych only return the array when given a `setTimeOut`. Else it returns `[undefined, undefined...]`.

my code looks like this:

```
getEntities: (type, offset, limit, query) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        seekKeys(type, offset, limit, query)
            .then((response) => {

                let entities = [];


                if (response.hasBeenFiltered) { // This is not used yet. 
                    for (let i = offset; i < response.keys.length && i < offset + limit; i++) {
                        entities.push(matchInstance(instance))
                    }

                    resolve(entities)

                } else { // here is where my issue's at.
                    console.log("Keys found: " + response.keys.length)
                    parseQuery(type, query)
                        .then((conditions) => {

                            let matches = response.keys.map((key) => {
                                readEntity(key).then((instance) => {
                                    logger.debug(instance); // logs instances.
                                    matchInstance(instance, conditions)
                                        .then((isMatch) => {
                                            logger.debug("isMatch", isMatch) // logs true/false ?
                                            if (isMatch) {
                                                entities.push(instance);
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .catch((err) => {
                                            logger.error("Failed to match entity: ", err)
                                        })
                                })
                                    .catch((err) => {
                                        logger.error("Failed to read entity: ", err)
                                    })
                            });
                            /*
                            Promise.resolve(matches)
                                .then(() => {
                                    setTimeout(() => {
                                        logger.debug("Match count:", entities.length);
                                        logger.debug("Matching entities:", entities) // logs result of entities
                                    }, 5000)
                                    //resolve(entities)
                                })
                            */
                            Promise.resolve(matches)
                                .then(() => {
                                    logger.debug("Match count:", entities.length);
                                    logger.debug("Matching entities:", entities) // logs [undefined, undefined ....]
                                    resolve(entities)
                                })

                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.error("Failed to parse query: ", err)
                        });
            })
    })
}`
```

The format is a bit broken. I'm quite sure why.
Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let matches = response.keys.map((key) => {
    // the mapping function:
    readEntity(key).then((instance) => {
```

The mapping function does not appear to return a value. This will create a mapped array with undefined elements.

```
let matches = response.keys.map((key) => {
    return readEntity(key).then((instance) => {
      // mapping function
```

may work better by filling `matches` with promises to read and process entities. Waiting for the promises to be fulfilled can be accomplished with `Promise.all`, so

```
 Promise.all(matches).then( ... process the entities array
```

is more likely to work than

```
Promise.resolve(matches).then( ... process entities
```

which won't wait for anything asynchronous unless `matches` is a pending promise - but if that were so, you would not need to resolve it before calling `then`.

Note the code indentation is confusing, so check the console for errors to see if `matches` is in scope when processed - I was unable to see that it was.